# Is "one of the single greatest" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms, british-english

> The Massacre is one of the single greatest historical tragedies in the history of the empire.

I understand "the single greatest" is common usage. But does adding "one of" before it make it illogical, or does it simply increase the level of emphasis?

Comment: What is the alleged ***grammatical*** violation here? Maybe that sentence no verb? No. Please  do not misuse "grammatical" in a way that has nothing to do with syntax or morphology.

Comment: Well, it's been fun looking at the examples in Ngrams. Although idiomatic in speech, I can't say I'd use any of the published examples as a model, and I think [this one](https://books.google.com/books/content?id=maQYAQAAIAAJ&pg=SL23-PA151&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U1EbIGjItmALF6ZbcZfyzrDiLgLbg&ci=546%2C156%2C336%2C316&edge=0) deserves a standing bloviation -  "[o] il spills are considered one of the single greatest potential impacting agents to the environment from offshore oil and gas activities."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tchrist mentioned in his [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/465153/is-one-of-the-single-greatest-grammatically-correct#comment1122734_465153), this is not about grammar.

However, there does seem to be a semantic issue with the sentence, because there can only be one *single greatest X*.

As @ParthianShot points out, there can be several *greatest X*, but surely there can not be any more than a single *single greatest X*.

That means that we can certainly have *one of the greatest X*, or *the single greatest X*, but not *one of the single greatest X*. It seems the author simply mixed up those two expressions - don't forget both are usually used as an hyperbole anyway, so often we don't even think about the actual literal meaning of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

I think your confusion here arises from your assumption that there can be only one greatest thing. In other words, you assume a strong ordering.

However, let's say that there are two people in the world who are equally fast. Both can run a mile in exactly one minute. The next closest runner can run a mile in three minutes.

In this case, there are two greatest runners, because they both have the best possible time, and neither is better than the other.  This is especially relevant in the case of something subjective like "greatest historical tragedies", since there are no standard criteria for comparing them.

So, it's perfectly logical, and not really a grammar question so much as a logic question. See the wikipedia article on [weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering).

Comment: "In this case, there are two greatest runners ..." Exactly. There are two. Not single.

Comment: "one of the single" is redundant because it's implied, but it's still logical. We're only focusing on one of the instances. We could instead be talking about "one of the greatest pairs of historical tragedies", for example.

Comment: No, you cannot be one of single.